# Mypy incompatible type doesn't recognize Union of Dataclass objects as key

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

MyPy is giving me an `incompatible type error` when the expected param type of a function is `Dict[Union[CustomObject1, CustomObject2], ...]` and I pass in `Dict[CustomObject1, ...]`.

Consider the following:

```
from typing import Dict, List, Union

import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyKey:
    myStr: str


@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class MySecondKey:
    myStr: str


@dataclasses.dataclass
class CustomDataObject:
    dataProp: Dict[MySecondKey, Dict[str, List[Dict[str, int]]]]


sample_data = {MySecondKey(myStr="a"): {"foo": [{"bar": 0}]}}
sample_prop = CustomDataObject(dataProp=sample_data).dataProp


def dummy_func(
    some_data: Dict[
        Union[MyKey, MySecondKey], Dict[str, List[Dict[str, int]]]
    ],
):
    print(some_data)


print(dummy_func(sample_prop))
```

The error is: `Argument 1 to "dummy_func" has incompatible
type; expected "Dict[Union[MyKey, MySecondKey], Dict[str, List[Dict[str, int]]]]"`.

Why is this happening? How can I resolve this issue?